# Grep a pattern in a line from log file and print next n lines until next patter

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

Suppose the file log.txt contains below content

```
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:30.080851 T(12581) _DBG message x 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:30.080851 T(34897) _DBG message y 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.241167 T(12344) _DBG message z 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.457612 T(34897) _DBG message y 2
                        test message line 2
                        test message line 3 
                        test message line 4 
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.78912 T(12344) _DBG message z 2
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:32.56341 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:33.12789 T(12581) _DBG message x 2
                        test message for x
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:33.78123 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
                        test message line 2
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:34.12342 T(12581) _DBG message x 3
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:34.56712 T(34897) _DBG message y 4
```

Desired output should be

```
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:30.080851 T(34897) _DBG message y 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.457612 T(34897) _DBG message y 2
                        test message line 2
                        test message line 3 
                        test message line 4 
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:32.56341 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:33.78123 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
                        test message line 2
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:34.56712 T(34897) _DBG message y 4
```

Given a thread ID, it should print the line + next few lines belong to that msg. Note that in the desired output, all other thread messages are removed.

I tried below sed command but it prints the next line also (which is different thread message)

```
sed -n -e '/T(34897)/,/_DBG/ p' log.txt
```

I tried other grep/awk/regex commands but couldn't get this done. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v t=34897 '/^\[/{f=($4=="T("t")")} f' file
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:30.080851 T(34897) _DBG message y 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.457612 T(34897) _DBG message y 2
                        test message line 2
                        test message line 3
                        test message line 4
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:32.56341 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:33.78123 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
                        test message line 2
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:34.56712 T(34897) _DBG message y 4
```

The above sets a "found" flag `f` every time it sees a line starting with `[`. If the 4th field on that line is `T(<target value>)` then `f` is set to true (1), otherwise false (0). When every line is read if `f` is true at that time then that current line is printed.

With any awk script if you'd like to see it with different formatting and less reliance on defaults to make it a bit less brief and more clear, you can pretty-print it using GNU awk (note: it must be gawk, not some other awk variant) as `awk -o- ...`:

```
$ awk -o- -v t=34897 '/^\[/{f=($4=="T("t")")} f' file
/^\[/ {
        f = ($4 == "T(" t ")")
}

f {
        print
}
```

Comment: I see a pattern and an action followed by a boolean.  And I see that it works.  But where is the boolean documented?  I can't find it in the gawk manual.

Comment: While that one-liner is indeed _very_ nicely Code Golfed, it is also very abstruse and its methodologies are rather opaque in comparison to my answer.  It is, though, at its core, the same solution in a more concise form.

Comment: @DopeGhoti that's why I added the explanatory paragraph below it.

Comment: @KenJackson are you referring to `f=($4=="T("t")")` or something else?

Comment: No @EdMorton, that's understandable.  It's the `f` after the first rule just before the closing single quote.  But I think I found the answer.  Gawk manual says "The requirement that states that rules on the same line must be separated with a semicolon was not in the original awk language;"  So you've written TWO rules separated by a space with no semicolon.  `f` is the pattern of the second rule which uses the default action which prints the line.

Comment: @KenJackson correct. I updated my answer to show how you can pretty-print awk scripts to get a heavier focus on clarity and what the output of that is for my script. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

With this awk script:

```
BEGIN {
  doprint = 0
  marker = "T("thread")"
}

$1 ~ /\[[0-9]+\]/ {
   if( $4 == marker ) {
      doprint = 1
   } else {
      doprint = 0
   }
}

doprint==1 { print }
```

invoked thusly:

```
$ awk -v thread="34897" -f 642963.awk input.txt
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:30.080851 T(34897) _DBG message y 1
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:31.457612 T(34897) _DBG message y 2
                        test message line 2
                        test message line 3
                        test message line 4
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:32.56341 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:33.78123 T(34897) _DBG message y 3
                        test message line 2
[12] 03/31/21 08:33:34.56712 T(34897) _DBG message y 4
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to set `doprint` in `BEGIN` because all variables are automatically initialized to zero in `awk`.

Comment: It's not necessary but I like to show the initialization explicitly so that people who may not know how `awk` (in this case) works may be more likely to intuit how it works rather than just copying a working "black box".

Comment: Don't name a condition variable (`doprint`) based on the action you'll take when the condition is true (print the current line) as that tightly couples the condition to the action. Imagine your requirements change and now you need to print the opposite set of lines to the ones you're currently printing. Because you named your condition variable `doprint` you'd now have to change every line of code that references it as `doprint` would no longer make sense. If instead you named the condition variable `found` or similar then the only change you have to make is `found==1` -> `found==0` or similar

Comment: Alternatively, one could keep the tightly coupled name and simply change the predicate of the `if` statement which determines whether its value is truthy or falsy.

Comment: Then your "else" statement would be a double negative as it'd represent the condition where it is NOT true that $4 is NOT equal to marker and of course double negatives should always be avoided (which is also one of the reasons to avoid using a single negative at all when you could use a positive).

Answer (score 0):

We first define some helper variables to assist in the formulation of field-based regexes.

```
# definition of a unit space
_s_='[:space:]'

# regex for a space char and nonspace char
s="[$_s_]" S="[^$_s_]"

# a field is a run of nonspaces followed by a run of spaces
F="$S\{1,\}$s\{1,\}"

   id=34897

sed -ne ":top
  /^\[$S*$s$s*\($F\)\{2\}T($id)$s/{
    :nxt
      p;n
    /^$s/b nxt
    b top
  }
" file
```